# Aggregate rows across some columns using ID and keep others unchanged in a large R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a large dataframe (6000rx42c) where I have an almost unique ID. There are some duplicates where one ID has multiple rows, which vary only by 2 numerical columns which I am happy to add up into 1 row.

I've spent ages looking and aggregate seems to work,however I need to list all columns I am keeping which is a pain. Can someone suggest a better solution? I am not wedded to aggregate.

```
NewDF <-aggregate(cbind(AddColl1,AddCol2)~ID+OtherCol1+OtherCol2+OtherCol3...OtherCol39 , DF , sum)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: `aggregate(cbind(AddColl1,AddCol2)~ID, DF , sum)`? Then `merge` with `DF`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thank you but I am not sure how that would work. The aggregation will remove my duplicates and leave me with say 5000 rows. If I try to merge these 2 columns with the original DF I'll have 6000 rows with some duplicates. I guess I can then use !duplicated?

Comment: `merge` has arguments `all`, `all.x` and `all.y` that you can set to `FALSE` as needed. Another option are the `dplyr::*_join` functions.